# Post to wall Error: contains a blocked URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

At the first time i use this code to test my apps with some post to my wall, its working:

```
$sendTo = $_POST['friend'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$attachment = array('message' => $message, 'link' => $link,  'message'  => $message);

$result = $facebook->api("/$sendTo/feed/",'post', $attachment)
```

And one day, i got this error, i dont know why?

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Sorry, this post contains a blocked URL thrown in /home/a3229328/public_html/MKK/exam/base_facebook.php on line 1033

Could any one tell me why and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the link you are trying to post?  Facebook block some urls, for example porn related things, piracy (pirate bay for example) and others sites which they file as inappropriate.

Comment: i even remove 'link' out of feed, just message: $attachment = array('message' => $message); And it also got error. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you just try to post a status message, without a link then my guess is that this error is caused by the trailing '/' you have there. In all of the documentation the urls for the api calls never end with '/'.

Try this instead:

```
$result = $facebook->api("/$sendTo/feed",'post', $attachment)
```

Notice that I used "/$sendTo/feed" instead of "/$sendTo/feed/"

Comment: Dear Tomer, i still get error "this post contains a blocked URL thrown in /home/a3229328/public_html/MKK/exam/base_facebook.php on line 1033"

Comment: Well, according to this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/ you should use: $facebook->api("/$sendTo/feed",'POST', $attachment) where 'post' is changed to 'POST'

Comment: Can you please try this: *$facebook->api('/me/feed','POST', array('message' => 'This is just a test'))* ?

Comment: :) no probs.  That means that you had a problem either in your $sendTo variable or the $attachment one.  Anyhow, since this answers your question, can you please make this answer is right? Thanks.

Comment: Where i can mark your answer is right, i can not see any button or something like that.

Comment: Its ok Tomer, but its still not working smoothly, sometime get error, i will contact you later if you are willing to help me ^^,

Comment: What error do you get? How often do you get it and what piece of code results in this error?